# How do I prevent a program from playing sound?

Tags: audio

I have a program which does not have an option to disable sound. I could mute the computer globally, but there are other programs for which I do want sound.

Is there any way to locally disable sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PulseAudio, you can just mute the application stream. With other audio systems, you'll probably need a NOP preload library to intercept the audio calls.